# como adicionar um if dentro de um .append() em JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Boa tarde prezados, tenho um append que cria uma lista dinamica, porem preciso fazer um if quando ele selecionar uma opcao em especifico ele ativa a condicao if que retorna uma modal, eu não manjo de jquery, se alguém souber agradeco muito, não encontrei em lugar algum como fazer isso.

Segue o append que estou tentando criar:

```
 $("#ulFiltroHomePeriodo").append("<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"seHome.atualizaPeriodoLabel('" + o.Value + "', '" + o.Text + "')\" data-value=" + o.Value + ">" + o.Text + "</a></li>")
```

Esse é o if que eu preciso fazer:

```
 if (o.Value == "porPeriodo") {
                $("#ulFiltroHomePeriodo").on("click", function () {
                    $("#ModalDatasContainer").modal().show();
                });
            }
```

Comment: Esta opção é " selecionada " através de um checkbox ?

Comment: Não, ela vem de um dropdown list dinamico, aquele append  monta a lista e o o.Value sao os Enumeradores com as opcoes, essas opcoes geram relatórios dinamicos, porem nesse caso eu preciso setar uma data inicial e uma final, eu criei a modal pra selecionar as datas, porem nao sei como fazer pra ele selecionar só aquela opcao dentro do if. Atualmente o modal aparecem em todas as opcoes.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isso te ajuda.
Criei uma lista de items usando também a propriedade data-value.
Ele verifica o valor dessa prop e exibe um alert se encontra o valor:

HTML:

```
<ul id="#lista"></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#lista").append("<li data-value='item1'>Item 1</li>")
$("#lista").append("<li data-value='item2'>Item 2</li>")
$("#lista").append("<li data-value='item3'>Item 3</li>")
$("#lista").append("<li data-value='item4'>Item 4</li>")

$("#lista").find('li').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).data('value')
    if(value === 'item1') {
      alert('Item 1 encontrado')
    }
  })  
})
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando, muito obrigado.